# How to center a button (.NET Compact Framework)

Tags: compact-framework

I want to centre a button in .NET Compact Framework. I dont see any property like StartPosition in .NET CF Form object.

Can someone please suggest me how to centre button in .NET CF 3.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean you want to center the button in it's container along these lines?

```
myButton.Left = myButton.Parent.Left + (myButton.Width / 2);
```

Comment: thx for answer but now is button align to right of the sceen it is not in the middle

Comment: button1.Left = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width / 2 - button1.Width / 2; this works. Thx for idea.